# Terrible with regex

Tags: php, regex

How can I make this regular expression replace spaces as well any non latin alpha numeric character?

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $title)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're terrible with regexes, maybe you should learn them.

Comment: Your reply to this question, has helped me learn a little more about them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^...]` matches anything but `...`.
`\s` matches spaces.

You don't want it to not match spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks ok, you just have to assing it to a variable!

```
$title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $title)
```

Comment: haha, that could be a problem (don't want to count the times I've done that).

Answer (score 1):

I would just do:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', $title, $out);
$ntitle = implode($out,'');
?>
```

EDIT: Briedis is right though, your regex works fine.